# Calculate relative probability in R

Tags: r

This is my data

[image]

I would like to get relative frequency for the whole data. I have no idea how to do this.  This is what I expecting for.
Output:

```
     relFreq
Black  0.183
White   0.05
```

and so on

Comment: It would be good if you could add your data in a format that is easier to use . Ie if you could edit your question with the results of `dput(mydata)` , rather than posting an image of your data. Thanks

Comment: SO is not a site to teach you R. This question shows a basic lack of understanding. You should learn the basics of R first.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do: `prop.table(table(c(mydata$FTMK, mydata$FKE, mydata$FKEKK)))`

Comment: also a little less typing `prop.table(table(unlist(mydata)))`

Comment: @user20650 good call -- that's actually better as I believe you will not lose the names with that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
table(as.vector(as.matrix(mydata))) / (nrow(mydata) * ncol(mydata))
```